# get value outside of function using jquery

Tags: jquery

Can you tell me how to get value outside of the function using jquery.

```
var getvalue;

$(':text').click(function(){

//here i am set this value in getvalue variable getvalue=$(this).val()

});

alert(getvalue);//i am not getting value here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var getvalue = null;
$(':text').click(function(){

//here i am set this value in getvalue variable getvalue=$(this).val()

});

alert(getvalue);//i am not getting value here
```

because there was syntax error

```
$(':text')
```

is not

```
$(":text')
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery event handlers allow you to pass arbitrary data to the function, which is accessed with event.data.

See http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/bind/

This works because, as the bind() page says, the original value of the variable will be changed when the function alters the variable:
"Note that objects are passed to functions by reference, which further complicates this scenario."

Note also the comment on the click() page from user Jason Simon, which says that the correct order of the arguments to click() is reversed:

"I believe the documentation is wrong, at least how I had to use it. It works like this:

.click( handler(eventObject), eventDataArray );"

```
var getvalue = null;

$(':text').click(function(eventData, eventObject){
    //here i am set this value in getvalue variable getvalue=$(this).val()
        getvalue = eventObject.data.someValue;
    });

alert(getvalue);//i am not getting value here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me!

Check jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6qp32/2/

```
<input type="text" value="val" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var getvalue;

$(':text').click(function(){

   getvalue = $(this).val()
});
a = setInterval('console.log(getvalue)', 500);
</script>
```